# Average vector of vectors in a set must belong to interior of the set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces

> Let $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a set with the property that if $x,y\in
>  C$ then $\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\in C$. Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $a\in
>  C, b\in \text{ interior} (C)$. I want to prove that in this case
>   $\vec{p}:=\frac{1}{2}(a+b)\in \text{ interior}(C)$.

Here's how I begin:

Need to prove that $\exists r>0$ such that the open ball $B(p; r)\subset C$. Since $b\in\text {interior}(C)$, $\exists s>0$ such that $B(b; s)\subset C$.

Unfortunately, I'm really stuck and would appreciate a hint or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (with some abuse of terminology): Note that the "average" between $a$ and $B(b;s)$ becomes $B(p;s/2)$.

Comment: Can you please clarify why exactly the radius of the ball is becoming $s/2$?

Comment: @sequence If the distance between $b$ and $b'$ is $r$, what is the distance between $p$ and $p'$? ($p'$ is the average of $a$ and $b'$.)

Comment: I see. I've just shown myself the distance is $\frac{1}{2}\|b-b'\|$. Now things are getting better. Thanks, @Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Let $z$ be a typical element in the open ball of radius $r$ with centre at the origin. Then $(a+b)/2+z=(a+(b+2z))/2$
and $b+2z$ is in a ball of radius $2r$ centred at $b$; this ball will be in the interior of $C$ for suitable $r$.